# Next.js getStaticProps passing data as object

Tags: javascript, next.js, javascript-objects, prisma, getstaticprops

I am new to working with typescript and next.js. I am using Vercel to deploy a Next.js webapp that will pull data from a heroku postgresSQL db using Prisma. I am trying to render some data on the page using observable/d3, using getStaticProps to fetch the data, then pass it to the Home page component.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    let data: Array<object> = await prisma.test.findMany()
    console.log(data)
    return { props: { data } }
}

const Home: NextPage = ( data ) => {
    console.log(data)
    useEffect(() => {
    document.body.append(
        Plot.barY(data, {x: "letter", y: "frequency"}).plot()
    )
 }, [])
 ...
}
```

The first console log in getStaticProps returns the data in my desired format, an array of objects:

```
[
 {letter: 'A', frequency: 0.0123}
 ...
 {letter: 'Z', frequency: 0.00234}
]
```

After passing the data to the Home component, `data` is wrapped in an object and looks like this:

```
 {
  data: [
   {letter: 'A', frequency: 0.0123}
   ...
   {letter: 'Z', frequency: 0.00234}
  ]
 }
```

My plotting function wants an array of objects, but after passing `data` using getStaticProps to the Home component, `data` gets 'wrapped' in those JS Curley braces and I don't want that. Can someone help me understand why and how to correct this behavior? Using typeof data in both console.log returns `object`

Comment: You should either destructure the props passed to the `Home` page component `({ data })`, or use `(prop)` and access the data with `props.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have been destructured the props `Home({ data })` instead of `Home(data)`

```js
import { InferGetStaticPropsType } from 'next'

type Test = {
  letter: string
  frequency: number
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  let data: Test[] = await prisma.test.findMany()
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}

// Destructure the props
const Home: NextPage = ({ data }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  // will resolve tests to type Test[]
}
```

Comment: If I have a couple of objects inside the data object, does it make sense to send it together as a single `data` prop, or split it into several individual props? Consider that the component represents a page which consists of several subsections, each of which takes one key from the `data` object.

Comment: If its all data retrieve from single API call I would send a single object data, again whether you send individual or all in once you need to destructuring that props anyway.

Comment: Yeah so if I have to destructure either way, is there any advantage to doing it via props? Like testing or something?